# Solution to a shared global variable constantly being changed or updated by all users?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was going to use Zend_Cache, but it says [here](http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/caching-data-using-zend_cache-with-example/) that it's not the best solution when you have a variable that is constantly being changed or updated.

What do you recommend? I want a priority queue that all users can change, update and share concurrently, without concurrency problems. This variable would live forever on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you'll need something that supports transaction and/or atomic actions.  Have you considered a RDBMS?  Also, what kind of traffic are you expecting on this site?  In other words, how good does the performance need to be.

Comment: I wish I wouldn't need a database. Performance is important. Do you think I could use Zend_Registry with atomic operations?

Comment: Is one user acting on this 'variable' or are multiple?  If it's multiple, then the data must be stored in some manner such that more than 1 request can access it.  Zend_Registry is specific per each request.  Your options for storage would be (overlooking a few) flat files with file locking, an RDBMS, or some kind of other datastore that provides atomicity.

Comment: Multiple users will read/write the same variable (in this case, add his or her IP address to a priority queue and read the head value). Maybe I could use a file locking solution. What Zend tool would you recommend?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if there is a Zend tool for that type of situation.  You could easily wrap the file logic up in an object.  Also, you keep saying "read and write the same variable".  Variables are specific to the instance of PHP running, thus multiple users cannot read or write to the same variable in the manner that you mean.  Anyway, if you're going with the file locking option, it should be straight forward to wrap the locking and insertion/reading logic in an object.  I can't right, but if you're still having problems later, I'll post a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think this also depends on what backend you are using for Zend_Cache. The default file storage is probably not be the fastest solution, but Memcached might look a lot different.

But it's important to remember that a cache is just that - it is supposed to make existing data available faster. If your shared variable should live on and you need transactions to avoid concurrency issues you will need some kind of persistence mechanism be it in a file or a database.

Comment: But since my variable changes constantly, I don't think caching with a db or file is a good idea. Do you know of something else I could use, that intrinsically takes care of atomic operations on a variable?

Comment: Are you actually having performance problems? Do you have a userbase big enough that the value will change more often than several hundred times a second? Your requirements seem to match exactly what a database does. PHP is single threaded by nature so you always need some kind of mediator to share state.